# reading FileInput; nextLine() doesn't work

Tags: java

This is my portefeuille which should contain all read 'woningen'

```
//read file
  public static Portefeuille read(String infile) {
    Portefeuille result = new Portefeuille();
    FileReader fileString;

    try{
       fileString = new FileReader(infile);
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileString);

       int amount = sc.nextInt();
       for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
          result.voegToe(readWoning.read(sc));
       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return result;
  }
```

This uses readWoning.read(sc) which is:

```
public class readWoning {
    public static Woning read(Scanner ac) {
        String toestand = ac.next();
        Adres adres = Adres.read(ac);
        int kamers = ac.nextInt();

        ac.next(); String aard = ac.next();

        int price = ac.nextInt();
        System.out.println(toestand + " " + adres + " " + kamers + " " + price);
        if("huurprijs".equals(aard)) {
          return new HuurWoning(adres,kamers,price,toestand);
        }
        return new KoopWoning(adres,kamers,price,toestand);
      }
}
```

This uses Adres.read(ac); which is:

```
public static Adres read(Scanner sc) {
        sc.nextLine();
        String street = sc.next();
        String number = sc.next();
        String code = sc.next();
        String place = sc.next();
        return new Adres(street, number, code, place);
    }
```

The file I want to read in is:

```
3
TE KOOP:
Emmalaan 23
3051JC Rotterdam
7 kamers
vraagprijs 300000
VERKOCHT:
Emmalaan 25
3051JC Rotterdam
5 kamers
koopprijs 280000
TE HUUR:
Javastraat 88
4078KB Eindhoven
3 kamers
huurprijs 500
```

Where the first number indicates how many woningen there are descripted in the file.
The first line shows the 'toestand'(state) in which the woning occurs, that could be: (sold, rented etc).
The 2nd and 3rd line indicate the address of a woning.
The 4th line indicates the amount of rooms inside the woning
The last line indicates the price of the woning.

Now my problem is:

I can't get Java read my file properly because of the toestand: "TE KOOP:"
I used String toestand = ac.nextLine() in my readWoning but it only outputs some spaces while String toestand = ac.next(); outputs only "TE"
If my question is somehow not specific enough just tell me.

Output I get:

```
TE Emmalaan 23, 3051JC Rotterdam 7 300000
VERKOCHT: Emmalaan 25, 3051JC Rotterdam 5 280000
TE Javastraat 88, 4078KB Eindhoven 3 500
null
null
null
```

Output I want:

```
TE KOOP: Emmalaan 23, 3051JC Rotterdam 7 300000
VERKOCHT: Emmalaan 25, 3051JC Rotterdam 5 280000
TE HUUR: Javastraat 88, 4078KB Eindhoven 3 500
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `if(aard == "huurprijs") {` should be `if("huurprijs".equals(aard)) {`

Comment: Oh indeed! Thanks, tho it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: This is a painful way to parse records from an input file. I would recommend using a BufferedReader instead of a Scanner, read each line individually and parse the ones that need to be parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use:

```
ac.nextLine();
String toestand = ac.nextLine();
```

Then toestand should contain `TE KOOP:`. `read` then skips the next line and starts looking for `street` at `3051JC`. Remove the `sc.nextLine();` from `read`:

```
public static Adres read(Scanner sc) {
    String street = sc.next();
    String number = sc.next();
    String code = sc.next();
    String place = sc.next();
    return new Adres(street, number, code, place);
}
```

and you should get:

```
TE KOOP: Emmalaan 23, 3051JC Rotterdam 7 300000
VERKOCHT: Emmalaan 25, 3051JC Rotterdam 5 280000
TE HUUR: Javastraat 88, 4078KB Eindhoven 3 500
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Sadly that doesn't work. Because when I print toestand. It shows that it only contains a double space.

Comment: @RaminErfani, it should work now, I had to move the `nextLine()` above reading `toestand`.